# Don't Row-equivalent, Inhomogeneous Systems of Linear Equations Have the Same Solution Sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, equivalence-relations

From **Hoffman and Kunze, Linear Algebra**, page 7, Theorem 3:

If $A$ and $B$ are row-equivalent $m\times{}n$ matrices, the homogeneous systems of linear equations $AX=0$ and $BX=0$ have exactly the same solutions.

Proof: Suppose we pass from $A$ to $B$ by a finite sequence of elementary row operations: $A=A_0\to{}A_1\to{}\ldots{}\to{}A_{k}=B$. It is enough to prove that the systems $A_jX=0$ and $A_{j+1}X=0$ have the same solutions, i.e., that one elementary row operation does not disturb the set of solutions.

So suppose that $B$ is obtained from $A$ by a single elementary row operation. No matter which of the three types the operation is (row exchange, multiplication of a row by a non-zero scalar $c$, or row replacement), each equation in the system $BX=0$ will be a linear combination of the equations in the system $AX=0$. Since the inverse of an elementary row operation is an elementary row operation, each equation in $AX=0$ will also be a linear combination of the equations in $BX=0$. Hence these two systems are equivalent, and by Theorem 1 they have the same solutions.

=============

Note:the authors define "equivalent" systems of linear equations as those for which all equations of the first system are linear combinations of the equations in the second system, and vice versa.

**Question**: why restrict ourselves to homogeneous systems? I see no reason to do this. I think the result applies perfectly well to non-homogeneous systems.

Comment: I think if you read on, you will see that Hoffman will say exactly what you are suggesting, before the first or second chapter is done

Comment: @311411 That makes me want to switch textbooks. As far as I can see H+K have already developed all the material needed to prove the result for general mxn systems (not only the homogeneous case) and the proof above works fine for the inhomogeneous case. Confusing.

Comment: For non homogeneous you need to use the augmented matrices.

Comment: i see no need to a priori pick one book on this topic, for all time. By all means read other books for a different point of view.

Comment: Just note that the exposition gets muddier, as the equation $AX=b$ must change to $A_jX=b_j$ for different vectors $b_0=b$, $b_1$, etc.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Actually, I think that is the reason for the confusion. H+K have not introduced augmented matrices yet even though they have proved that solution sets of " equivalent" systems (homogeneous or not) are equal. So after they pass to the matrix view they are unable to prove this simple and powerful result for the inhomogeneous case. A very weird choice.

Comment: @311411 I started in Axler but by Chapter 2 the author is asking us to solve systems of equations in the exercises despite never introducing the subject. I searched for a book which develops the theory of systems of equations rigorously and H+K is the best I've found. Basically switching between them at this point but plan to make Axler my main text after I feel strong on systems.

Comment: Personally I like HK, I disagree with this Linear Algebra done right stuff, its against determinants.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus The final chapter of Axler's book has material on determinants. Axler seems to believe that determinants are a lousy tool pedagogically and that they obscure the elegance of the subject. Why do you disagree?

Comment: @Gary Yeah I disagree with that, first determinants are one of the oldest parts of Linear Algebra, pushing them to the side creates a warped view of the subject. Second they have many applications in other fields of math, many key arguments relying on them. Finally, I think they  are elegant, and motivated.  Some people feel that determinants have no motivation, but that is just not the case. Pedagogically he is doing a disservice to his students by not treating them in their proper place in the subject.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thanks for your response. I intend to study a determinant-heavy approach to linear algebra after I complete Axler. Maybe Shilov's book. I am open-minded.